# Replace blank values in one column based on partial string values of another in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like the following:

```
pig<-data.frame(a=c("","","","","","Type1"),b=c("T1 NR","T2 NR","T2","T3","T3","Type1"))
print(pig)
  a      b
       T1 NR
       T2 NR
       T2
       T3
       T3
Type1  Type 1
```

Where a will sometimes be blank, but b always has information that corresponds to the missing information in a.  I am looking for two things.  First, where "NR" is present in b, I want "NR" to appear in a.  Second, where "NR" is not present in b and a is blank, I would like some other string to appear in such as "DKT" to get something like the following:

```
cow<-data.frame(a=c("NR","NR","DKT","DKT","DKT","Type1"),b=c("T1 NR","T2 NR","T2","T3","T3","Type1"))
print(cow)
 a     b
NR   T1 NR
NR   T2 NR
DKT   T2
DKT   T3
DKT   T3
Type1 Type1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse);pig %>% mutate(a = case_when(str_detect(b, "NR") ~"NR", a == "" ~ "DKT", TRUE ~ as.character(a)))`

Comment: Using *ifelse* `ifelse(pig$a == "", ifelse(grepl("NR", pig$b), "NR", "DKT"), as.character(pig$a))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign using row/column subsetting with a  `data.frame`.

```
# You're doing string editing, so let's avoid factors from the start
pig <- data.frame(
  a = c("","","","","","Type1"),
  b = c("T1 NR","T2 NR","T2","T3","T3","Type1"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# The actual solution
has_nr <- grepl("NR", pig$b)
pig[has_nr, "a"] <- "NR"
pig[!has_nr & pig$a == "", "a"] <- "DKT"
```

Comment: I get an error when applying the last line: `Error in chatToDate(x): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` I think it might be an issue with the blanks, which could be a different question.  However, any thoughts?

Comment: What's the class of the `a` column in your dataset?  Is it a `Date` vector?

Comment: It is class `character`

Comment: I'm guessing the error actually says `charToDate` instead of `chatToDate`.  If so, somewhere in your code you're attempting to convert a character value to a Date, but it's unclear how to interpret it.  Even if you're not calling `as.Date()` yourself, you might be assigning a value into a Date vector.

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo.  I convert another column to a date, but not the one I am working on.  What would be the best way to go about fixing the issue?

Comment: `as.Date` will try to guess the format, but it won't try very hard.  As a rule, always provide the `format` argument.  For example, to parse today as a "squashed date," you would use `as.Date("20180122", format = "%Y%m%d")`.  See `?as.Date` and `?strptime` for how to specify different formats.